# PHP SimpleXML datetime data set/convert timezone

Tags: php, datetime, format

Need the dates & times I'm getting from Highrise API via PHP/cURL to be output in EST.

```
// functions.php

function hr_xml($acct, $path) {
    // HTTP Authentication
    $url = curl_init('https://' . $acct . '.highrisehq.com/' . $path . '.xml');
    curl_setopt($url, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($url, CURLOPT_USERPWD, '..................:x');

    curl_setopt($url, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($url, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

    $data = curl_exec($url);
    curl_close($url);

    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
    return $xml;
}

function get_day($tdVal) {
    $input = substr($tdVal, 0, 10);
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $input);
    $date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('EST'));
    return $date->format("l");
}

function get_time($tdVal) {
    $input = substr($tdVal, 11, 5);
    $time = DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i",$input);
    $date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('EST'));
    return $time->format("A g:i");
}
```

This works on my localhost where the default timezone is UTC but not on my production server where the default time zone is America/Los_Angeles; there it's putting the times that should be 10am EST and were 2pm on both my localhost and production before I added the setTimeZone bits, on my localhost now what should be 10am is 10am and on production now it's 5pm. What the hell.

Comment: Ok I added date_default_timezone_set('EST'); before those functions and now on my localhost 10am is 3pm. I didn't change the setTimeZone bits. What the ffff

Comment: I set the prod. server default timezone to UTC since my local default was UTC and then it worked.